# how to send email from results generated as array from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, email, html-email

i am using the following query:-

```
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT item,quantity,price,(quantity * price) as total FROM saleitems_T WHERE invoice = '$inv' ");
```

i am trying to use the while loop inside the mail body but it does not work. following is the code.

```
$to="someone@somewhere.com";
$headers="Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$body = '
<html> <body>
Invoice details are as follows.<br />
'.while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
echo "<table><tr><td>";
echo $row['item'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['quantity'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['price'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['total'];
echo "</td></tr>";} .'
</table></body></html>';

mail($to,$body,$headers);
```

the no of lines retrieved varies on each invoice. Now i want to send the results as an email. any help with sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first you have to study how send a email in php

Comment: i have added the code that i'm using but this does not work.

Comment: completely wrong syntax. you can't do `$string = 'ss' . while(..){..}`

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov i am new to this language. that's why i am seeking help.

Comment: @mmdel at least you need to look at PHP documentation, [while](http://php.net/while), [echo](http://php.net/echo), [mail](http://php.net/mail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$to = "someone@somewhere.com";
$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$body = '<html><body>Invoice details are as follows.<br />';
foreach( mysql_fetch_array($qry) as $v ) {
$body .= "<table><tr><td>{$v['item']}</td>"    
         . "<td>{$v['quantity']}</td>"     
         . "<td>{$v['price']}</td>"  
         . "<td>{$v['total']}</td></tr></table></body></html>";       
}

mail($to,$body,$headers);
```